# Android contextmenu item size / height, how to change?

Tags: android, menu, contextmenu

How can i change the contextmenu item's size? height?

Thanks, 
Leslie

Answer (score 1):

It's not really intended to be modified - it's there to handle menu in standard way. There are some ways to modify the menu  and its items (for example see here: http://www.techjini.com/blog/2011/04/19/customizing-background-and-text-color-in-options-menu-android/) but I really think in this case you are far from the original menu idea...

Far enough to simply create your own view - whatever you like it to be and show it when handling long press.. You can make it embedded in your own transparent full screen control... I think it will be much faster than modifying context menu.