# How can I shrink my contextMenu?

Tags: java, android, contextmenu

I'd like to trim the excess white space in the right hand side. Is this possible and if so how can I do it?
Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpful for you: [Android contextmenu item size / height, how to change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478249/android-contextmenu-item-size-height-how-to-change) , so yes is much like creating your own implementation of the context menu.